# Getting started with graphhopper

Tags: java, class, web, graphhopper

I'm getting start with a graphhopper sw, i've installed the maps but now i'm developing the sw in java code.

```
GraphHopperAPI gh = new GraphHopperWeb();
gh.load("Address-of-maps");
```

And it required graphhopper classes but, where i can find these classes??

Comment: Please see our quickstart

Comment: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.3/docs/index.md